# Git reset branch to remote/master keeping logs

Tags: git, branch, commit, reset

I think I know the answer but I'll ask anyhow.

I work mainly on a fork with branching. So I have `upstream` and
`origin` where the latter is my fork.

Then I create branches like `origin/new-feature` (from now on
`nf`). Nothing exotic. :)

So after experimenting for a while in `nf` and having it pushed the
experiments to `origin` the work I've done it's not gonna fly.

Reset my local and origin with

```
$ git checkout upstream-master
$ git pull
$ git checkout nf
$ git reset --hard upstream/master
$ git push --force
```

now the question. Are there any way to keep the history of my old
commits in the same branch?

If I'd liked to keep them I would have created a new branch
`origin/nf-abandoned` before going for the reset above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is what `git rebase` is for.  It will operate on the checked-out branch (the source) and a branch given on the command line (the target) and will replay the history of the source up to the point where it diverges from the target onto the target as new commits, but retaining the author timestamp as well as the commit messages.

```
$ git checkout origin/new-feature
$ git fetch upstream
$ git rebase upstream/master
$ git push --force origin new-feature
```

The result: (C is the commit you originally branched from)

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E (original origin/new-feature)
           \-- F -- G (upstream/master)
                     \-- D` -- E` (rebased origin/new-feature)
```

Note that your commits D and E get rewritten as D` and E` on top of `upstream/master`, keeping the history linear.

Alternatively, you can instead merge `upstream/master` into your branch and continue development, if the project will accept such a pull request.  The advantage of this approach is that the exact history will be recorded, including the merge action, which means that `--force` isn't required to push your branch back to `origin`.

```
$ git checkout origin/new-feature
$ git fetch upstream
$ git merge upstream/master
$ git push origin new-feature
```

The result:

```
                    v (original origin/new-feature)
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- H <- (post-merge origin/new-feature)
           \-- F -- G --/
                    ^ upstream/master
```

Comment: thanks @cdhowie but I don't think this is what I was looking for (I can be wrong). I was looking for a way to have my commits rewritten with upstream, kind-of discarded if you like, but still in the history. In my real use case I simply wanted to reset the branch and drop the commits; but what if I'd like to keep a history of it happening.

Comment: @davide Both of these approaches will keep them in the history, just different ways. The merge approach will record that a merge happened, the rebase approach will instead rewrite the commits to exist on top of `upstream/master` with no record that they ever existed in a different place in the history of the repository.

Comment: thanks for your patience @cdhowie but I don't want to keep the old commit on top of upstream master. I'd like to have my commits, completely rewritten by upstream/master. Something like `reset --hard` do; but keeping track of them in the history so that if I do a `git log -p` I can still see the old commit. As said so far I always solved with a reset --hard and in case I wanted to keep the old commits, create either a patch file or a squashed branch.

Comment: @davide Your desire to retain the old commits as visible with `git log` and also not have them in the history are completely at odds with each other -- `git log` shows history, but you don't want them in the history. You can't have it both ways. You *can* retain the old history on a separate branch treated as an archive branch, but then I'm not sure what your question really is. It may help to diagram the repo's initial state and the state in which you want it to be. If you do that, I can help you get there.

Comment: nevermind. You just confirmed what I was suspecting. The branch/diff approach is the only way. Thanks for patience and support.

Comment: @davide No problem. Note that `git format-patch` provides a mechanism to archive commits as "mbox" files. This mechanism is used by the Linux kernel developers to email branches to each other, but it can also be used to archive a branch to files that exist outside the repository. I've used this command to take commits made on a production box with read-only access to the repo over to a dev box where I can push them. (Obviously, the commits wouldn't be available in `git log` if you drop the branch later, but you'd still have the patch files from which you could recreate the branch.)